# Get the $this in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my issue.

HTML structure :

```
<tr><td><a ng-click=aClick()>Click Me</a></td></tr>
```

I cannot have any id/class associated with the  and

What I require is that on the click of 'Click Me', the `<tr>` gets hidden.  I need a jQuery solution. Some how I am not able to use `$(this)`.

FUNCTION:

```
$scope.aClick = function() {
   $(this).parent().parent().css('display','block');
};
```

But this statement gives me an error.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: it says that no .parent().

Comment: $scope.$apply() works wonders for those who would like to do this the angular way.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal what is the callback you are talking about ? Where is the callback coming from ? Are you doing $.ajax or $http ?

Comment: No. I am actually executing db statements.

Comment: http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/this-in-angularjs  nice article about this in angular

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Note: I wouldn't recommend using dom manipulation in a controller, you can write a directive to do this. That said you can use the `$event` to get the event object, from which you can get the event target and use it with jquery.

```
<tr><td><a ng-click="aClick($event)">Click Me</a></td></tr>
```

And

```
  $scope.aClick = function(event) {
     $(event.target).parent().parent().css('display','none');
  };
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/auHr7zKbAQO3sPybBRE6?p=preview)

**Update**
A more appropriate angular solution will be is to use ng-hide

```
<tr ng-hide="hideRow"><td><a ng-click="hideRow = true">Click Me</a></td></tr>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BBOdNae7oWy5fUi73fqw?p=preview)

[Updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/N8lxRbeiHpbguCNZjHz6?p=preview) with ng-repeat

Comment: This is a solution to the problem but it is not the right solution. This solution is tightly coupled with the structure of your html. I know @Arun P Johny was giving you a solution to solve your immediate problem but I think he should refrain from doing so. It is a disservice to the rest of the developers ( mostly to the next developer who is going to be working with this code! ).

Comment: @ganaraj yes as I've noted in the answer it is just to solve the problem he is facing.

Comment: The correct solution will be is to use a scope variable to set the display status of the parent

Comment: @ArunPJohny I know you mentioned that. But the strange thing is I dont think he noticed.
Thanks for the update :). I know you actually know the right solution ( I have seen your other answers ! ).. I just want you to lead with the right solution first and then if they insist.. provide  the wrong one :)

Comment: @ganaraj did you see the last update, i think it should solve the problem correctly

Comment: @ArunPJohny Disagree with the updated solution. It is not the _appropriate_ solution here. It will work only if there is one row. But in a table, this is usually not the case. For multiple rows, the updated solution would just not work. You need a function to check if the current row (index?) is to be shown or hidden - that would be the more _appropriate_ solution

Comment: @user2104976 in that case you can use a map to save the state

Comment: @user2104976 or if it is inside a ng-repeat each row will have its own scope

Comment: @ArunPJohny TIL that each item in a `ng-repeat` directive has its own scope! Anyway, I feel that we must still use a function instead of direct assignment to a scope variable from inside the HTML.

Comment: @ganaraj - first of all ..its a SHE. Girls do use SO too. And second ...mayb the update might work for others who may face the similar issue t will not work for me as the variable on which ng-hide is called is updated in a callback function and thus, ng-hide does not get updated. If we are looking for the most appropriate answer then $scope.$apply is the right solution.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal sorry for the confusion. Whether the variable is updated in a callback or not you should still not require to do $scope.$apply() unless you are using a third party library to make your http requests! ( are you ? ) . You said you are making db requests ? I did not understand that. How are you making db requests from the client side?

Comment: @ganaraj - I am using the local Db of HTML5 - web sql. In the call back of the excutesql I need to update a variable i.e only when the query has successfully executed. When i try to access this var (using two way binding) in ng-hide, its value is not reflected unless i use a $apply

Comment: @BhumiSinghal You should probably create a service for your localDB. This service should inject $rootScope and call $rootScope.$apply() when you get back values from it. This is how $http works internally. If you do this, you wont have to call $scope.$apply everywhere..

Comment: @ganaraj - ohh!! Actually since i am getting this issue only at one place, i guess i can avoid the creation of the service .. :)

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using angular, you should very seldom need to do actual dom manipulation. Instead, check out the [ng-hide/ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHide) directive that should do this for you.

An example from the Angular docs:

```
<body>
    Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br/>
    Show: <span ng-show="checked">I show up when you checkbox is checked?</span> <br/>
    Hide: <span ng-hide="checked">I hide when you checkbox is checked?</span>
</body>
```

**Edit**

If the variable in the expression is updated asynchronously, you can force an updated with [`$scope.$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

Comment: As i said i require jquery to do my work. The constraint with ng-hide is that the variable on which it is called is updated in a callback function and thus, ng-hide does not get updated.

Comment: Then you should be able to force an update with [`$sope.$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: Ohk this works too and i am glad i know about it now as I would love to use only angular through out. Adding $scope.$apply(); to the end of the callback function resolves the issue. I wish i could accept this  answer too ....

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

**JavaScript**

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe = function ($event) {
        $($event.target).parent().parent().css('display','none');
    };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <a ng-click="clickMe($event)">Click me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/vfMzk/2/)**

Comment: Definately works ....But Arun posted the answer before and that is more accurate to what i need ... so only a +1.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do something simple like this?
I assume you run this in loop...

```
<div ng-repeat="row in table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <a ng-class="{'hideme': hiddenRows[row.id]}" ng-click="hiddenRows[row.id] = true">Click Me</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</div>
```

or even better

```
<div ng-repeat="row in table">
    <tr ng-show="!hiddenRows[row.id]">
        <td>
            <a ng-click="hiddenRows[row.id] = true">Click Me</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

(I didn't test it but it should give you idea)