# Angular ng-keypress event to modify input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to modify my input value and separate it using dash `-`

```html
<input type="text" ng-keypress="addHyphen($this)" id="sortcode" name="sortcode" maxlength="6" ng-model="data.branchTransitNumber" />
```

For achieving the same I wrote a `ng-keypress` event and trying to modify the input.

```js
$scope.addHyphen = function(ele) {
   console.log(ele);
   //var ele = document.getElementById(sortcode)
   var finalVal = ele.match(/.{1,2}/g).join('-');
   document.getElementById(sortcode).value = finalVal;
}
```

The code gives `ele` as `undefined`. I have even tried getting the element by idea but it also gives `undefined`.

**Input: 11111**

**While typing : 11-11-11**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how did you get into `$this` but the event handler passes only `$event`

> Expression to evaluate upon keypress. (Event object is available as $event and can be interrogated for keyCode, altKey, etc.)

<sup>https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress#ngKeypress-arguments</sup>

The right way to get the element is `angular.element($event.target)`

Like this:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', $scope => {
    $scope.addHyphen = $event => {
      const $this = angular.element($event.target);
      console.log($this);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <input type="text" ng-keypress="addHyphen($event)" id="sortcode" name="sortcode" maxlength="6" ng-model="branchTransitNumber" />
</div>
```

Reference: [Get the $this in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16163978/863110)

Comment: But isn't this a non-angular way to achieve this so to speak? Data is already in the model, can't we use filter?

Comment: No that I know. This is the way. You don't have to wrap with `angular.element` if you don't need (for example, if you want only the value of the input)

Comment: BTW, input-mask already done by some libraries. Read this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39938066/863110

Comment: I don't prefer input mask in my case. As I need to send a POST request with the dashes